# TFS Reporting capabilities

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I have no knowledge about the reporting capabilities of the Team Foundation Server as we have it installed without them.

Now the company wants to generate a report with the hours each person entered each day. Is this possible using the reporting tools of TFS?

Comment: Was the team foundation server data warehouse installed with it? Or does this fall under the "reporting capabilities" you describe above?

Comment: @AndrewBay: we did a standard installation without sharepoint or SSRS. When I talk about reporting capabilities I talk about the reports that TFS generate thru SSRS.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the downvote was already explained by (first part of) the tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort". [This article](http://whathaveyoutried.com) is a decent explanation why that is important IMO. In addition, you can use [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to create great questions; not all of the points apply to this kind of question but the general idea of it is solid.

Comment: So you are asking me to search what SSRS is, download it, install it, configure TFS to use it and then search if the kind of report I need is doable with this unknown (to me) technology? I thought that this site was great because you can ask to someone that already has the knowledge on that area so he can answer you that question and save you kind of 15 - 20 hours ...

Comment: And by the way, that link has nothing to do with my question. I'm not asking for any solution. All I ask is if something is doable or not. I don't see nothing wrong in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to now configure the reports as part of TFS even though you did not do so earlier.

- [Add a Report Server to Your Deployment](http://bit.ly/11ZWDvx)

**Yes**, it is *possible* to report on the number of hours entered into TFS by user each day

**No**, it is not a good idea and this is an extremely poor metric to monitor and will likely result in a manifestation of negative behaviours in your team / individuals.

**No**, it is not possible to do time sheets in TFS.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the team is formed mainly by contractors. Each contractor's company sends us a monthly bill with their work. We want to compare the company bill with the amount of hours entered into TFS because they must mach. Makes sense to you? Thanks!

Comment: Very bad idea. I can guarantee that the numbers will match, even if the consultants have to lie to make them match. Hear me on this: TFS IS NOT A TIME TRACKING SYSTEM.

Comment: Ok, I see your point but it will be hard for me to defend users having  to enter their time information in two different tools. How do you handle that?

Comment: They are not entering their time information twice... they are entering their effort in TFS and their timesheets in another system

Answer (score 2):

There is another alternative (paid with free trial): http://www.tfs-timetracker.com.
It is fully integrated into TFS and focuses on tracking time people spend. It's compatible from TFS 2012 up to the latest version (currently TFS 2013 Update 2). (I'm from the team, I hope you accept me 'advertise' our solution in this thread.)

Answer (score 1):

TFS is not a system for tracking "the hours each person entered each day". Forgetting about the reporting for the moment, you must first ask where such data would be coming from? Do you have a customized work item type that you use for entering time?

If the data are present in work items, then you can certainly use the integration with Excel. You can create a work item query and easily open the query in Excel. That will give you the data, and you can do further formatting and analysis using the tools built in to Excel.

Comment: Yes, each Task contains the Estimated work, work done and work remaining. We want to use that info to generate time sheets and to check that the reported contractor time equals the reported TFS time.

Answer (score 1):

By the way I've found some tools related with time tracking with TFS:

- Free:

  - [TFS Timesheet](http://tfstimesheet.codeplex.com/)
  - [TFS Timesheets](http://tfstimesheets.codeplex.com/)
- Paid:

  - [Team expand](http://www.teamexpand.com/page/tfs-timesheet-application?p=g&gclid=CLCA-ZeOi7UCFXDLtAodPl4Acw)
  - [Imaginet](http://www.imaginet.com/MicrosoftALMAdoptionServices/Pages/default.aspx)

Only the 2nd option will work out of the shelve with TFS 2012.

Comment: http://www.teamexpand.com/product/tx-chrono - is pretty cheap and flexible tool. It provides you with convenient and simple user interface, bidirectional sync with TFS and report-generating functionality. It supports all modern TFS versions and network environments.